# 2D Array Map switching neighbor elements - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

i am struggling with a project.
I am trying a 2D Array Map task, where there is a single value - e.g. "1", that conquers all the neighbor "0" values. - horizontal and vertical.

This is my code so far:
`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TakingOver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] map = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        int conquer= 1;


        
        
        int horizontal_direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1; // random move left or right
       
        int vertical_direction = Math.random() > 0.5 ? -1 : 1; // random move up or down

        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {

                if (map[i][j] == conquer) {
                    map[i][j] = 2; // place a "2" of the previous location of conqueror

                    // if the newRow exceeds the boundaries, don't move in that direction
                    int newRow = i + horizontal_direction;
                    if (newRow < 0 || newRow == map.length)
                        newRow = i;

                    // if the newCol exceeds the boundaries, don't move in that direction
                    int newCol = j + vertical_direction;
                    if (newCol < 0 || newCol == map[i].length)
                        newCol = j;

                    map[newRow][newCol] = conquer; // move conqueror to the new position
                    System.out.println();
                   // System.out.println(newRow + "     " + newCol);
                    break;


                }

            }
            for (int[] x : map) {
                for (int y : x) {
                    System.out.print(y + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

`

My input should be 2D array like this:

```
int[][] map = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
int conqueror= 1;
```

and output like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 
0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 
0 0 0 0 2 
0 0 0 0 1 
.......
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 1    until all the values are "conquered"
```

but i get half the result -

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 
0 0 0 0 2 
0 0 0 0 1
```

My input should be 2D array like this:

int[][] map = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
int conqueror= 1;

but i get half the result -

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 2 0
0 0 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 1

Answer (score 0):

Ts 2 D array the best solution for this? Can you try implementation with switch case?

Comment: that's my next idea, i will remove the for loops and create x,y, grid and simplify things a little bit